# .htaccess to deny directory access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to restrict access to directories in my root so that others cannot access the files in those dir directly in a browser. Problem I am running into is now the pages in the root for example the index.php is asking for a password and the .htaccess is in the root of the directories and not the root of the domain. This is preventing the index file from accessing include files from those directories.

What is a simple way to lock down those directories from browser access while still allowing the files in the root to access them and vistors being able to access the root pages without being asked for a password. I would like to to be as far as they know they site is viewable but, if someone starts prying around in the sub directories to steal code it will deny them but, allow the pages to access them.

I have tired this in each of the directories I have been wanting to restrict direct browser access to.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Administrator"
AuthUserFile /home2/mesquiu0/.htpasswds./htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
Allow From 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add the following line with an extra empty line to disable indexing the directories:

```
Options -Indexes
```

See Documentation for more info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

Comment: I will give this a shot too. I had tried it previously, cleared cached and restarted browser and I was still able to access files in a directory. I may have done +Indexes though so that may be why. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Tried this as well both in the directories and in just the root and if you right click on index or any file in a root and click a link it will take show that file in that directory in the browser which is what I am trying to prevent. Anyone accessing the sub directories directly from a browser while still allowing the files in the root or other sub directories to access them which they may be included from.

Comment: Update, this works for restricting access to the directory but, if some views the source of the file and clicks on a link for example, the stylesheet. It will allow them to view the file within that directory. If I just try to view the directory structure then it blocks them. I need them to not be able to access the files in the directory while still allowing the files to be included in certain files that need them.

Answer (score 1):

Just allow the scripts that match php, aspx, etc.

apache 2.2

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Administrator"
AuthUserFile /home2/mesquiu0/.htpasswds./htpasswd
Require valid-user

#Forbid access to any files except from localhost, because of Order Deny,Allow, Allow gets applied later.
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

#Allow access to files matching index.php
<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

In Apache 2.4 the rules has changed, and the correct syntax is to use `Require all denied` instead of `Deny from all`.

This is for apache 2.4

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Administrator"
AuthUserFile /home2/mesquiu0/.htpasswds./htpasswd
Require valid-user

Require host 127.0.0.1

#Allow access to files matching index.php
<Files index.php>
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will give that a shot. My web host is on Apache 2.2 which is surprising as they are usually pretty good about staying current. Just one small question. Do I need to put this in the root or in each directory as I have it now and I assume if I have multiple file extensions I just add a | to add a new one?

Comment: I tried this out putting it in each dir as well as trying it in the root. If I put it in the directory it still doesn't let the index access the files and it asks for a login. If I put it in the root it locks down the entire site. I just need to lock down the directories but still allow me option to log into those directories while at the same time allowing files in the root to access files in those sub directories.

Comment: Please check now! If it still does not work, i will request you to update your htaccess contents and directory structure in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess file put the following line

Deny from all

And this if you like to put exceptions.

allow from all

Comment: This won't work as it also restricts files from being included.